# Dates or dated in relationship

Tags: tense

I came across a word today that I am confused about. If 2 people are currently dating, should I say:

1. He dates you because you're funny.
2. He dated you because you're funny.

The first one sounds like it's correct but if I was talking about when the relationship was first started and still happening, should I use the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question, Nah Man. The first one is correct because the relationship is (presumably) still on-going. However you would want to add "is" to the first and "was" to the second.

> He's dating you because you're funny.

And if the relationship has ended:

> He was dating you because you're funny.

In the first example, you're would have to mean "you are" whereas in the second example it could be either "you are" (because you're probably still funny) or "you were" (because you were funny when he met you in the past).

Finally, if you wanted to say that this is the sole reason that he's dating you, you could simply add:

> He's only dating you because you're funny.

Good luck!